# multiple android devices using same email address question/

Tags: email

I work for a company which uses many android devices (tablets). Same level of users share same email address. When an email is sent to a group,they all get the emails but only one of them is receiving the email alert from the tablet. Is there any way to configure the tablets to have all of them alert when new email is received? We use Samsung Galaxy tablets with Android. Thank You.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment on [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125320/16575): As soon as someone reads the mail (or dismisses the notification), no more notifications will be done – as the recipient has "acknowledged" the information. I doubt there's a way around that other than using separate mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think other tablets didnt turn on the notifications of New arriving emails. 
Go to email -> settings -> 1.tick the EMAIL NOTIFICATIONS.
And also check you have tick the SYNC EMAIL.

Comment: That should work – until someone receiving an alert dismisses it (or reads the mail). From that point on, no more alerts will be "delivered".